# In postgres, does an advisory lock expire after a set time or does the session expire in idle automatically?

Tags: postgresql, locking, postgresql-9.5, pg-promise

I have a need to hang on to an advisory lock for about 30 seconds while my application instances come online. I noticed that if I do a `setTimeout` with a callback to release the lock, with 30 seconds or more, I get a warning that I don't own a lock of type ExclusiveLock. (If I call setTimeout with 10 seconds, this doesn't happen)

```js
    setTimeout(async () => {
      try {
        await sync.tryLockRelease(lockName) // call to pg_advisory_unlock(id);
        log.info(`${metadataKey}: lock released`)
      } catch (err) {
        log.error(`${metadataKey}: could not release lock: ${err.message}`, err)
      }
    }, 30000)
```

If I add an interval that queries the DB every second, this problem doesn't happen. This leads me to believe that the session is being culled at some time greater than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there's a setting in pg-promise (which gets passed to the underlying node-postgres library) called `idleTimeoutMillis`, which can be set in the [Connection Syntax](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Connection-Syntax) page of pg-promise. However, it appears there is still an outstanding issue where the underlying driver is not respecting the value: https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2139

Comment: That issue should not effect you, as the Connection Syntax pages tells you, just pass it with the connection parameters, and it will work.